# Eigenvalues and more of $\lambda^2$, where $\lambda$ is a general $su(3)$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a general $su(3)$ matrix in usual Gell-Mann basis $\lambda = l_a \lambda_a$, with $a=1,...,8$. Are there any resources studying the eigenvalues /eigenvectors of
$$\lambda^2 = \frac{2}{3} l^2 I + d^{abc}l_a l_b \lambda_c \quad ?$$
For one, I have computed the eigenvalues (which should be real, given  $\lambda$ is hermitian) with the help of Mathematica and certain $su(3)$ structure constant identities to be 
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{2}{3} l^2 - \frac{1}{3}R^{1/3}- \frac{1}{3}l^4R^{-1/3}\\
\lambda_2 = \frac{2}{3} l^2 + \frac{1}{6}(1-i \sqrt{3})R^{1/3}+ \frac{1}{6\sqrt{3}}(3 i + \sqrt{3})l^4R^{-1/3}\\
\lambda_3 = \frac{2}{3} l^2 + \frac{1}{6}(1+i \sqrt{3})R^{1/3}+ \frac{1}{6\sqrt{3}}(-3 i + \sqrt{3})l^4 R^{-1/3},
$$
where 
$$R=-6(d^{abc}l_al_bl_c)^2 +l^6+2|d^{abc}l_al_bl_c|\sqrt{3(d^{abc}l_al_bl_c)^2-l^6}$$
But I'm not entirely sure I can trust these or if there are simpler, less cryptic ways of writing them. I have learned from eq. 3.14 from doi:10.1007/BF01654302 that the argument of the square root is always negative but Mathematica complains about taking cubed roots when I try to give it numerical values respecting that (which I imagine comes from secret assumptions it made while solving the cubic characteristic equation).

finding eigenvectors seems rather difficult..

Comment: Interesting. But what is the question?

Comment: Principally, I'm looking for resources on this material. If anyone has diagonalised $\lambda^2$ in the literature...

Comment: I would state it more clearly in the text what you're looking for. I think you would get more response. $\lambda$ is the most general traceless  $3\times3$ matrix. It's eigevalues, in general, will be roots of a cubic (summing to zero). The same holds for $\lambda^2$, except that it's not traceless. You seek an expression in terms of $\ell$s? You can easily do a numerical check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be cryptic.

For a generic 3×3 matrix, the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix) yields a direct expression which, for your traceless case, reduces/collapses to 
$$
\lambda^3= \lambda {1\over 2}\operatorname{tr}\lambda^2 + 1\!\! 1 {1\over 3}\operatorname{tr}\lambda^3 , 
$$
so that 
$$
 \operatorname{tr}\lambda^3  = 2 d^{abc} l_a l_b l_c \equiv m , 
$$
supplementing your 
$$
 \operatorname{tr}\lambda=0, \qquad       \operatorname{tr}\lambda^2 = 2l^2.     
$$

But these traces suffice to  determine the eigenvalues *n* of *λ*, whose squares you are seeking, $\lambda_i=n_i^2$,
$$
n_1+n_2+n_3=0, \qquad n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=2 l^2, \qquad  n_1^3+n_2^3+n_3^3=m= 3n_1 n_2 n_3 ~,   
$$
without fancy use of specific basis identities... The characteristic equation is *already* in [depressed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) with non-negative discriminant $(2l^2)^3 /2- 3m^2$.

For the irredeemably lazy amongst us, consider $l=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-\sqrt 3)$, so $2l^2=6$, *m* = 6, hence vanishing discriminant. Hence your $n_i$ are -1,-1, 2, and your $\lambda_i$ are 1,1,4.