# Is it possible to construct a basis of SU(2) using SU(3)?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, physics, unitary-matrices

Using the Gell-Mann matrices for SU(3), can one construct a basis for SU(2)?

That is, is there a linear combination over the 8 Gell-Mann matrices:

$$
\sigma_x=\sum_{i=1}^8 a_i\lambda_i\\
\sigma_y=\sum_{i=1}^8 b_i\lambda_i\\
\sigma_z=\sum_{i=1}^8 c_i\lambda_i
$$

such that $\sigma_x,\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_z$ are $3\times 3$ matrices with the following properties:

$$
\sigma_x\sigma_x=1\\
\sigma_y\sigma_y=1\\
\sigma_z\sigma_z=1\\
\sigma_x\sigma_y+\sigma_y\sigma_x=0\\
\sigma_x\sigma_z+\sigma_z\sigma_x=0\\
\sigma_y\sigma_z+\sigma_z\sigma_y=0\\
$$

Comment: Bases are linked to structure constants. You are not implying $\sigma_x,\sigma_y, \sigma_z$  satisfying the exact same Lie algebra as the Pauli matrices? You probably know *this* is impossible, given the eigenvalues of your 3x3 ones having to be 1, 0, -1, in that case.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687312/eigenvalues-and-more-of-lambda2-where-lambda-is-a-general-su3-matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous. If you are seeking three 3×3 hermitean traceless matrices which satisfy the same Lie Algebra as the Pauli matrices, than you know form elementary angular momentum theory that the eigenvalues of each 3d irrep matrix are 1,0,-1, and so you cannot satisfy $\sigma_x^2=1\!\!1$.

If, instead, you are just just looking for three 3×3 hermitean traceless matrices 
which satisfy your anticommutator conditions, this too is not achievable. To have 
$\sigma_x^2=1\!\!1$, you need, w.o.l.g., one eigenvalue 1 and a double eigenvalue -1 for $\sigma_x$, so, then, a characteristic polynomial $(n-1)(n+1)^2$, which has a non-vanishing quadratic term: [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) for a traceless 3×3 matrix.